# how to get selecteditem of combobox in dataGrid while selectionchanged is handling

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, selecteditem

I have a datagrid like this :

```
<datagrid itemssource="{Binding Path=ProdCommande, ElementName=CommandeWindow}" autogeneratecolumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="produitDateCommande" Binding="{Binding dateCommande}" Width="120" Header="Date Commande"/>   
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Statut ">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatutCommande, ElementName=CommandeWindow}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatut, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</datagrid>
```

All I want it is to get the selected item in combobox help!

Comment: I suppose the trick is where are you trying to get the selected item from (code behind, viewmodel)?  Based on the code you posted, it looks like you should just be able to retrieve it from the CommandeWindow.SelectedStatut property.

Comment: I'm using code behind. but I can't get selecteditem

Comment: @AmineAntri what exactly is stopping you? is selectedItem null?

Comment: i can't even get the control (combobox) object itself

Comment: @AmineAntri look at my answer and see if that helps. you must cast the sender as a ComboBox to get access to it.

Comment: @AmineAntri also please post your code from the code behind so we can see what you have so far

Comment: @AmineAntri was this ever resolved?

Comment: yes problem solved. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are casting the `sender` as a `ComboBox`.

For example:

```
   private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    var item = cb.SelectedItem;
}
```

then you should be able to cast the `SelectedItem` to whatever type it should be.